# What's the square brackets for when definining an object?

Tags: javascript

I noticed somewhere that we could define an object using the following syntax:

```js
const a = {
  ["test"]: 1,
  ["tmp"]: 2,
};
```

Is it the same as the following one?

```js
const b = {
  "test": 1,
  "tmp": 2,
};
```

If so, what's the `[]` for in the first code block?

Comment: With `[ ]`, the property name can be any arbitrary expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an ES6 feature called *Computed Property Names* 
When using it a great benefit is you can also put variables as key name. Like for example a string which includes variables

```
const a = {
  [`obj${someVariable}`]: 1,
  [`obj${anotherVariable}`]: 2,
};
```

```js
const someVariable = 4;
const anotherVariable = 3;
const a = {
  [`obj${someVariable}`]: 1,
  [`obj${anotherVariable}`]: 2,
};

console.log(a)
```

Here are a few examples

- http://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript